# Basement Watchdog Battery Acid

Tags: sump-pump

I have a Basement Watchdog Special System & needed to replace the battery. Just filled all the cells & waited & rechecked the level & are all exactly at the line on the BW Battery & the probe is in the correct cell.
The add distilled water light stays on. System appears to be functioning correctly but why does that light stay on even with this new battery?

Comment: Is this a lead / sulfuric acid battery ?

Comment: I don't understand, did you *actually* replace the battery, or did you just add water?  How old is the battery?

Comment: It sounds like the concentration of acid is high and adding distilled water may be needed to bring the level to the proper ratio. Charging and testing with a hydrometer is an old school method most auto parts stores sell battery hydrometers for 5-10$

Comment: It is a brand new Basement Watchdog lead / sulfuric acid battery & I added the battery acid to the top fill line indicated on the battery itself. I've replaced these before & never had an issue & didn't have to supplement with distilled water until months later. Everything is connected correctly as before & all wiring is in good shape. Seems to be working: just has the add distilled water light on & alarm goes off every 24 hours Until I reset it again. –